# swift Table View секции

Tags: swift

Пытаюсь сделать разделение на секции, что бы получилось примерно так 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался так :
(в `listСountries` - хранятся заголовки, в `listMathcesInСountries` хранятся значения, но все разом, по этому я циклом прохожу и отделяю для каждой секции свои значения (метод `createSect`), в `sectionData` все правильно сформировалось)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
var sectionData = [String: [String]]()

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var id = Int()
    var searchResult = Array<String>()
    var searchController = UISearchController()


    @IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return listСountries.count
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return listСountries.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
//        if searchController.isActive {
//            return searchResult.count
//        }

        let key = listСountries[section]
        if let value = sectionData[key] {
           return value.count
        }

        return 0
      //  return (listСountries.count)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
        guard let index = listСountries.index(of : title) else {
            return -1
        }
        return index
    }
    func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return listСountries
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        var  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }

        print(indexPath.row)
        let key = listСountries[indexPath.row]
        if let value = sectionData[key] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = value[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func tableView( _ tableView : UITableView,  titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)->String? {

        return listСountries[section]
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        let headerView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        headerView.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.orange
        headerView.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 25.0)
    }




    private func tableView (tableView:UITableView , heightForHeaderInSection section:Int)->Float
    {
        return 50.0
    }


    func createSect() {


        for (index,item) in listIndex.enumerated() {

            var tempSection = Array<String>()
            var IndexFromTo = item.components(separatedBy: "-")
            for (index, match) in listMathcesInСountries.enumerated() {
                if (index >= Int(IndexFromTo[0])! && index < Int(IndexFromTo[1])!){
                    tempSection.append(match)

                }
            }

            sectionData[listСountries[index]] = tempSection
        }
    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createSect()

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    TableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false


    self.TableView.reloadData()
}
```

но результат выходит такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в результате у всех секций одни и те же значения, а если листнуть вниз, то выйдет ошибка в строке  `cell.textLabel?.text = value[indexPath.row]` - индекс все границ массива. Подскажите, где я допустил ошибку ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых у вас ошибка в той строке где ругается компилятор:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = value[indexPath.row]
```

Обратите внимание, к примеру `indexPath.row == 5`, вы достаете страну под индексом `5` из списка стран и потом из массива городов `value` вы достаете сразу пятое значение.

Во вторых, вам необходимо доставать значение из списка стран под индексом секции:

```
let key = listСountries[indexPath.section]
    if let value = sectionData[key] {
        cell.textLabel?.text = value[indexPath.row]
    }
```

**UDP:** Добавление изображения для заголовка

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 60))
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "picture")
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        return view
    }
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: не подскажите, а как в заголовок добавить изображение ?

Comment: @Lolidze добавил обновление